# Windows Phone 7 Font

Tags: windows-phone-7, fonts, typeface

I'd like to ask a question about Windows Phone 7. I'm really interested in what font is used for the app names on the tiles:

[image]

I know that the font for WP7 is Segoe WP, but I've checked Segoe WP Light/Semilight/Semibold/Bold/Black plus Segoe UI and Zegoe but no match. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally thought it was just standard Segoe WP (since the font looked the same as when I generate standard text for the tiles using the default [PhoneTextNormalStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), which uses normal Segoe WP), but upon closer inspection it's actually Segoe WP Semibold. I did a few mockups in Paint.NET and you can tell - the thing that threw me off is that the calendar tile's text content *also* uses Segoe WP Semibold.

I had a trawl through the [design guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202884%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) and it doesn't mention which font is used for the Live Tile titles, but I'd trust the Silverlight Toolkit as mentioned.

Comment: Huh, alright, thank you. I tried it and it looks way too thin in Photoshop. :/

Comment: Yes, it's probably the Semi-bold then. Render some images, with the same letters, to get the precise comparision. Mostly looks like a antialiasing issue though.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the toolkit's `HubTile` control.

I grabbed the code from there, as you can see it is Segoe WP SemiBold.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="BackTitleBlock" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" Margin="10,0,0,6" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
```